# How to eval program output in PowerShell

Tags: bash, powershell, rust, clap

I've written a command line utility in Rust, with argument completion provided by the `clap_complete` crate. This generates Bash and PowerShell completion scripts:

```
$ ex --completion=bash
_ex() {
    local i cur prev opts cmd
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    cmd=""
    opts=""
...
```

```
$ ex --completion=ps
using namespace System.Management.Automation
using namespace System.Management.Automation.Language

Register-ArgumentCompleter -Native -CommandName 'ex' -ScriptBlock {
    param($wordToComplete, $commandAst, $cursorPosition)
...
```

I can support argument completion in new interactive Bash sessions by updating my `.bashrc` file with this line, which uses process substitution to evaluate the command output:

```
source <(ex --completion=bash)
```

How can I do the same thing in PowerShell?  I've done a lot of Googling, and found plenty of pages describing how to *call* external scripts, such as with the `Invoke-Expression` cmdlet, but nothing that tells me how to *eval the output* of external scripts.

Comment: You mean like `Invoke-Expression $(ex --completion=ps)`? If the CLI outputs on multiple lines, use `Out-String`, eg. `Invoke-Expression $(ex --completion=ps |Out-String)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Invoke-Expression` doesn't call a script, it evaluates a string. So the first step is to evaluate, which is basically the same as in bash.

```
ex --completion=ps
```

If this was one line, this would be a string, but it's multiple lines, so this returns an array of strings. You need to join them. `Out-String` is one way of doing that.

```
ex --completion=ps | Out-String
```

This can be fed into `Invoke-Expression`.

```
ex --completion=ps | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
```

You can put this line in your powershell [profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/shell/creating-profiles).